# 2004 Schweitzer problem 4

Tags: number-theory, functional-equations

Determine all totally multiplicative and non-negative functions $f\colon\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}$ with the property that if $a, b\in \mathbb{Z}$ and $b\neq 0$, then there exist integers $q$ and $r$ such that $a=qb+r$ and $f(r)<f(b)$.

2004 Schweitzer Miklós Problem 4

So far, I've learned that

1. $ f(0)=0 $
2. $ f(1)=f(-1)=1 $
3. $f(x) = f(-x)$
4. $ f(n) \ge \log_{2} ( n+1 ) $ for $n > 0$

And of course guess the answer to be
$f(n) = |n|^c$ where $c \in \mathbb{Z^*}$

Any other clue to this problem?

Comment: Note that, using an [Approach0 search](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24f(r)%5Clt%20f(b)%24%2C%20OR%20content%3A%24a%3Dqb%2Br%24%2C%20OR%20content%3Atotally%20multiplicative%2C%20OR%20content%3Anon-negative&p=1), there's the AoPS thread [Multiplicative function](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1298676p6907048). Also, the question text from "So far, I've learned that ..." to the end is identical to Post #$2$ there by Aywu. In addition, Post #$8$ has a link to [Euclidian algorithm-ish function](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h2869579p25489147).